# Does it matter if I kill Amodar or Lightning first?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

So, I have been fighting these guys for like a day and a half, and so far I have only captured Lightning. So here's my question, since its easier to kill Amodar first, what if  I get him first then Lightning? Does the tamable monster depend on which one I kill last or doesn't it matter?

Comment: Anyway to hide this as Spoiler?

Comment: @Fredy31 This is referring to the Coliseum DLC, which has no bearing on the plot at all.

Comment: Oh, thanks.

I played XIII-1 and was thinking "WHAT? You kill Lighting in the XIII-2??? OMG SPOILER" but if you say so, that's means that the story has not been spoiled. For me, that is.

Comment: @Fredy31 Like a bad Sci-Fi plot, time paradoxes are a relentless deus ex machina in FF13-2, allowing you to defeat Lightning in the coliseum without actually affecting anything at all.

Answer (score 2):

I killed Lightning first both times just because that guy is an absolute tank and got both of them. Helps if you have that mog extra to make turning enemies to crystal easier.

Answer (score 1):

I killed Amodar and received his crystal first. It does not matter which order you kill them in. Personally I found the battle easier killing Amodar first because he can cause a lot of status ailments.

Answer (score 1):

Kill Amodar first if you want Lightning's crystal vice versa for Amodar's.

Answer (score 0):

I have reason to believe that by killing one of them first, you negate the possibility of retrieving his/her crystal/rare item. This aroused my suspicion when I was desperately trying to get Lightning's crystal and item. I always destroyed Amodar last, and kept on getting *HIS* things, so I decided to finish him off *FIRST* and right off the bat I received both Lightning's crystal and item.

Of course it must also help to be on Normal like I was, and this is just a hunch.

Comment: Considering the other answers already posted above, I feel that the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Monster crystal acquisition does not depend on the order in which you kill them: it's highly unlikely the mechanics are different for this specific battle.

Comment: I suppose that the odds just decided to favor getting my crystal the first time I decided to switch to killing Amodar first. Like I said, it was just a hunch, and no form of Internet research would have helped me speak otherwise, to be sure.